# LTSpice Frequency variable source

Tags: simulation, ltspice

Using LTSpice I'd like to simulate a L-C parallel resonant circuit; I'd like to check its .tran behavior, but I don't know how to simulate a frequency variable voltage source similar to a Frequency Signal Generator in which I turn the frequency value to look for the tuning value.
How can I do ? Is it an example I could use to do it?

Comment: Why not run an AC analysis?

Comment: You could use the .step facility

Answer (score 2):

Add a B source with a time value in the parameter"

For example put this in for the value of the B-source:

> V=0.00205*sin(2 * pi * time * (1 + (2 * time)))

time is a system variable, so you are essentially doing this:

$$ V = A\sin(2\pi t*(1+\beta t))$$

The amplitude can be varied with A and the frequency with \$\beta\$, you can also choose other equations, there are if statements and other neat things you can do to generate a source.

You either have to do math or play with the values to get the starting frequency and ending frequency.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want a `.tran` analysis of a swept frequency, besides the already given answers, you can also use `[SpecialFunctions]/modulate` or `modulate2`. It's easier to use than a behavioural source and it handles large dynamic ranges much better, despite needing two additional sources for that. You may also need some buffer at the output since it defaults to `Rout=1`, but it can be lowered/raised as needed.

For example, for a `1s`, `10Hz - 100Hz` sweep, from `1V - 2V`, you can add a `PWL(0 10 1 100)` source to the `FM` input, and a `PWL(0 1 1 2)` source to the `AM` input, with `mark=1 space=0` added to the `modulate`.

You can also combine the two inputs to a single source. In this case, the amplitude will be directly controlled by the source, thus it will have to be `PWL(0 1 1 2)`, while the two parameters will need to be calculated from the formula: `f = space + (mark - space)*V(FM)`, which, for `1V` initial and `2V` final results in `mark=10` and `space=-80`.

Here's a quick setup:

[image: schematic]

The input is flat `1V` until `0.5s`, ramps up to `2V` until `1.5s`, then stays flat, to make the frequency detector show clearly the final values.

Comment: I would try solution you suggest: where I can find U1 as component to put into my schematic?

Comment: You don't need `U1`, that's just some home-brew frequency detector. All the setup is made of `A1` and `V1`. If you can't combine the two inputs (`FM` and `AM`) to be driven by one source, only, then you'll need two, driving each input, separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a .tran simulation with a varying frequency, parameterise the voltage source freqeuncy as {expression}, where expression is a function of the 'time' variable. The 'time' variable takes the time of the present simulation step in seconds. Check your documentation for the exact format, it may be capitalised.

It may be cleaner to set the frequency to zero, and control the phase as an expression of 'time'.

Answer (score 0):

There are already a few different examples/ways given to do this, but since it exists and it's a little different with a logarithmic frequency step in time, here's another.

[image]
Image source, explanation, and simulation download: [eewiki](https://eewiki.net/display/Motley/LTspice+Tips+-+BI+and+BV+Arbitrary+Source+Examples#LTspiceTips-BIandBVArbitrarySourceExamples-ASinusoidalVoltageSourceWithaPeriodicLogarithmicFrequencyStep)

I figured it may help someone else who stumbles on this while searching.

Comment: nonya_business, you have been creating a new account every time you log in here, rather than using the original one. This is why you can't edit "your" posts -- the system believes that they actually belong to a different account. This practice also makes it impossible for us to communicate with you privately, which is why I'm leaving this as a public comment, in hopes that you will see it. If you really want to contribute meaningfully to this site, please stop creating multiple accounts and try to work within the rules established by StackExchange.